# SQL query optimization on cross production?

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following schema

- CUSTOMER (CID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(30), ADDRESS VARCHAR(50))
- PRODUCT (PID INTEGER  NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), PRICE DECIMAL(10,2))
- SALE (SID BIGINT NOT NULL, STATUS VARCHAR(10), CID INTEGER, TOTALPRICE DECIMAL(30,2))
- PRODUCTSALE (SID BIGINT NOT NULL, PID INTEGER NOT NULL, UNITS INTEGER,   SUBTOTAL DECIMAL(30,2))

I am currently have a statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    P.NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT C.CID) AS NUM_CUSTOMERS 
FROM 
    CUSTOMER AS C, PRODUCT AS P, PRODUCTSALE AS PS, SALE AS S 
WHERE 
    C.CID = S.CID
    AND S.SID = PS.SID 
    AND PS.PID = P.PID 
GROUP BY 
    P.NAME 
ORDER BY
    NUM_CUSTOMERS  DESC
```

I think it's creating a four table(P,S,PS,C) cross product? Can I optimize it by using nature join on four of them? What are the other way of optimize this statement?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Primary Keys and Foreign Keys would not hurt.

Comment: What version and platform of Db2 are you using?

Comment: Also, do you really want to allow NULL for e.g. PRODUCT.NAME, STATUS, CUSTOMER.NAME. Better to make column NOT NULL unless you realy do wany to lets nulls in

Comment: Your decimals are rather large. Do you really need 28 significant figures in DECIMAL(30,2).. Something like DECIMAL(17,2) would likely be more than sufficient

Comment: @marc_s can you verify that would result a cross join resulting a Cartesian Product which would harm the performance? Nice to hear it from a Nova Scotian.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the biggest table and filter down.

```
SELECT p.NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT c.CID) AS NUM_CUSTOMERS
FROM ProductSale ps
INNER JOIN Product p ON ps.PID=p.PID
INNER JOIN Sale s ON ps.SID=s.SID
INNER JOIN Customer c ON s.CID=c.CID
GROUP BY p.Name
ORDER BY NUM_CUSTOMERS DESC
```

Comment: @Paul Vernon I think INNER JOIN perform better than cross product? I am new, and that's what I want to verify with experts here.

Comment: Db2 will re-write the queries to the same internal form in this case. Also the original post is not really a Cross Product, it is just that the joins are in the WHERE which is fine, just old style SQL

Comment: @Paul Vernon according to w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php, SELECT foods.item_name,foods.item_unit, company.company_name,company.company_city FROM foods,company; results a Cartesian Product. I thought my question is the same?

Comment: the WHERE C.CID = S.CID  AND S.SID = PS.SID  AND PS.PID = P.PID  in your question stops it from being a cross product to all intents and purposes